# Why am I getting a cannot read property props error for my function passed to a child?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So I have a button which updates an array stored in my back-end, I need that button to also update the state of my front-end with the new array from the back-end. I am passing a function which changes the state of the parent to the button but when I try to call that function with this.props.function() I get a TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined.

I have another button which uses basically the same code(except this one I call the passed function inside another function which I bind to onClick) and works perfectly fine so I am confused as to why this one is not working.

Parent:

```
//within constructor
this.onUpdateRooms = this.onUpdateRooms.bind(this);

//function
onUpdateRooms(list) {
    this.setState({roomList: list});
    console.log(this.state.roomList);
  }

//within render
<GenerateButton onUpdateRooms={this.onUpdateRooms}/>
```

Button

```
//within the class declaration
constructor (props) {
        super(props)
    }

onCreateNewRoom() {
        const newRoomCode = GenerateRandomCode.TextCode(6).toUpperCase();
        console.log(newRoomCode);
        let temp;
        fetch('/api/newRoom', {
            method: "post",
            headers: {
              'Accept': 'application/json',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({roomCode: newRoomCode})
        })
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(list => temp=list);

        this.props.onUpdateRooms(temp);
    }
//then i set the button's onClick={this.onCreateNewRoom}
```

I can't seem to figure out whats wrong. I've been deleting and adding things for the last 2 hours. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you also need to call `bind` on `onCreateNewRoom`

```
constructor (props) {
        super(props);
    this.onCreateNewRoom = this.onCreateNewRoom.bind(this);
    }
```

you could also use arrow functions to avoid re-binding `this` and this kind of mistakes:

```
onCreateNewRoom = () => {
```

So `this` inside of `onCreateNewRoom` will be bound to the class and not the `onClick` handler function.

> The bind() method creates a new function that, when called, has its this keyword set to the provided value, with a given sequence of arguments preceding any provided when the new function is called.

In the constructor `this` is bound to the class. When you call `this.onCreateNewRoom.bind(this)` you are setting `this` inside of the `onCreateNewRoom` to the value you pass as the first argument to `bind`. (Which is the `this` bound to the class and contains `props`).